# how to log in to this web page automatically

Tags: c#, authentication, httpwebrequest

http://www.conquerclub.com/game.php?game=13025037

Please does anyone know how I can programatically log onto this address and then get all the html of the page back as a string Using something like HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse.

username - "testuser1"

password - "testing"

(I've created an account on the site with these credentials so it will actually logon)

So far I've got this

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.conquerclub.com/game.php?game=13025037");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    richTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This automatically re-directs and returns the html of the login page. How do I pass the username and password to login automatically so it retrieves the game page instead?

I know there are quite a few similar questions on this and I've spent several hours trying different things but can't get anything to work.

Edit:-

Looked into this further and this site uses cookies for logging in.

Tried this code but is still just returning the login page.

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string loginUri = "http://www.conquerclub.com/login.php";
    string username = "testuser1";
    string password = "testing";
    string reqString = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

    CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginUri);
    request.Proxy = null;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.CookieContainer = cc;
    request.Method = "post";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = requestData.Length;
    using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
        s.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.Cookies != null)
        {
            foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name + " = " + c.Value);
        }
    }

    string newloginUri = "http://www.conquerclub.com/game.php?game=13025037";
    HttpWebRequest newrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newloginUri);
    newrequest.Proxy = null;
    newrequest.CookieContainer = cc;
    using (HttpWebResponse newresponse = (HttpWebResponse)newrequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream resSteam = newresponse.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resSteam))
        richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Have found that the code at the bottom to log into the game page can be made to work by first logging in manually while using fiddler on firefox then copy and pasting the cookies and hard coding them into newrequest like this.

```
string newloginUri = "http://www.conquerclub.com/game.php?game=13025037";
HttpWebRequest newrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newloginUri);
newrequest.Proxy = null;
newrequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
newrequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://www.conquerclub.com"), new Cookie("PHPSESSID","86bte1ipainiq760vm2flv4h13"));
newrequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://www.conquerclub.com"), new Cookie("phpbb3_jer7c_u", "648113"));
newrequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://www.conquerclub.com"), new Cookie("phpbb3_jer7c_k", ""));
newrequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://www.conquerclub.com"), new Cookie("phpbb3_jer7c_sid", "3eebb0771a68c4a58581e495c34b2c93"));
using (HttpWebResponse newresponse = (HttpWebResponse)newrequest.GetResponse())
using (Stream resSteam = newresponse.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resSteam))
    richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

This returns the game page as I want it to but can't figure out how to get the login working so that it will return the right cookies. On debugging the code the cookies that come back are completely different to the ones I'm seeing in fiddler so looks like it's just not logging in.

Comment: Simplest thing to do would be to manually log in and using Fiddler, watch the request that gets sent. You can then reconstruct that request in your code.  (Note: it doesn't look like they are using SSL so you shouldn't have to enable any of the HTTPS features in Fiddler but for future reference you could if you needed to.)

Comment: Yeah done that and I can now get it to log directly into the game page but only by copy pasting the cookies from fiddler and hard coding them. I can't figure out how to make it log in automatically and retrieve the relevant cookies.

Answer (score 2):

The code that you've written does a GET of the URL given; however, to retrieve the content of the page when you log in you need to pretend that your WebRequest is actually filling in the form, by passing in all the form variables and issuing a POST request instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx gives a good walkthrough of the steps you require. The following isn't 100% complete, but should give you a step in the right direction:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.conquerclub.com/login.php");
request.Method = "POST";

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
    { "username", "testuser1" }, 
    { "password", "testing" }, 
    { "redirect", "game.php?game=13025037" }, 
    { "direct", "63###www.conquerclub.com###" }, 
    { "protocol", "HTTP" }, 
    { "submit", "Login" } };

var content = string.Join( "&", ( from p in parameters select p.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode( p.Value) ).ToArray() ); ;

byte[] bytes = new byte[content.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(content.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write( bytes, 0, bytes.Length );
dataStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Note that `content` includes various values that aren't visible on-screen; these can be seen by viewing the form's source, or (easier) by using the 'Network' tab on your browser debug toolbar of choice and monitoring the data being sent when the form is submitted.

Comment: That's great thanks. I've almost got this working now. The only thing I can't figure out is where the "direct" field comes from. using fiddler I can log in manually, copy and paste the value into my code to generate a cookie then log directly into the page I want. The only thing is that the value of direct changes for different users. The page source is <input type="hidden" name="direct" id="direct" value="yes" />. Please do you know where it gets this value from and if there is a way I can obtain it automatically.

Comment: There is a function login() defined halfway down the code, that is obfuscated; it may be that this is designed to stop people scraping it. Try throwing it through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and seeing if you can make any sense of it.

Comment: Incidentally, the hex array just before the login() function can be decoded by jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rLZUH/. So you may be able to manually piece together the original javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mimic the process of logging in. Look at the HTML code for the login page, and find out three things:

1. The `<form>` that sends the request, specifically the target (found in the attribute `action`) of the form.
2. Find out the method of sending the data (found in the attribute `method`)
3. Find the ID of the fields that represent the user name and password.

Having those you can easily construct a WebRequest that mimics a login.

Note, that this assumes a straight forward login screen (no AJAX, no CAPTCHAs).

Comment: This is pasted from the page source - <form class="ccform" action="login.php" method="post" onsubmit="login();">
<fieldset>
<legend>Login</legend>
<div class="field-row">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="field" name="username" id="username" autofocus maxlength="16" value="" tabindex="1" />
</div><div class="field-row">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" class="field" name="password" id="password" maxlength="16" tabindex="2" />
</div>

Comment: I don't have any idea how to construct a WebRequest from this.

Comment: @Oli - Then it's time to do some homework and study up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That's a possibility although it seems like a bit much spending hours learning a whole new topic just to do one thing. I was really hoping someone could just tell me how to do it.

Comment: @Oli - Welcome to programming. That's how you learn stuff and become a better programmer. You may or may not use this knowledge again, but you've become a better coder by just learning.